# How to show the query inside PHP?

Tags: php, sql

i have a SQL query
and i want to insert it  in a PHP file
this is it

```
SELECT SUM( value )
FROM table name
WHERE field_id
IN ( 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41 )
```

i want it to appear in the browser as

**the total is** : "value of the SQL"

can you help me please

Comment: [Yes we can.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Did you try ? Show the code you tried.

Comment: `<?php echo 'the total is: "SELECT SUM( value )
FROM table name
WHERE field_id
IN ( 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41 )"'; ?>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this (example with mysql):

```
    $conection = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","")
        or die("Can't connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db("database name") or die ("Can't connect to the database");
    $sel="SELECT SUM( value )
        FROM table_name
        WHERE field_id
        IN ( 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41 )";
    $query = mysql_query($select,$conexion) or die ("Bad.");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Now, $row is an array whith the first row resultant. So $row[0] is your result.
To catch the next one just repeat:

```
&row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the mysqli library, the documentation is here: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

An overview:

- Create a database connection
- Execute the query
- Grab the result set